# Relativity thought experiment - spaceship travelling at speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, relativity, thought-experiment

I have basis knowledge in special relativity, but I haven't studied it for too long and I'm stuck in a simple thought experiment. Assume that there is a spaceship departing from the earth at speed of light (I know it is not possible but it's just a thought experiment). There is a clock in the spaceship with time 00:00 as it leaves the earth. As the clock reaches 00:30, the spaceship sends a light signal to the earth. Since the speed of light is constant relative to any inertial frames, the light signal approaches the earth at the speed of light in a frame rest to the earth (despite red shift which should render the light signal to zero frequency but I think it's not relevant here?), and the signal is received on earth, the observers on earth see that the time on the clock was 00:30. The spaceship keeps sending signals and the time on the clock changes for the observers on earth. However, according to the relativistic time dilation effect, a time interval on the spaceship should correspond for an infinitely long time on earth, which contradicts to the result of the thought experiment, that the observers on earth would see the time on the clock updating. So what's wrong with the thought experiment there?

Comment: The observers on earth will never receive any signal because the signal will never be send (for them). It would take an infinite amount of time for the observers on earth before the persons in the spaceship send that signal.

Comment: I was trying to obtain the results from the time dilation effect from the first principles in relativity, i.e. the speed of light being constant and all inertial frames being equivalent, so this argument sounds like a circular argument to me.

Comment: even thought experiments cannot violate the laws of physics if they are to be of any use.

Comment: On this site, we prefer thought experiments that don't break the laws of physics. ;) If you make tbe speed microscopically less than $c$, then we can calculate when the observers on Earth will receive the signals from the ship.

Comment: You can use Lorentz transformations to convert times & distances from one inertial frame to another. The problem with your thought experiment is that there is no inertial frame that moves at $c$ relative to any other inertial frame, or equivalently, there is no inertial frame in which light from any other frame is at rest.

Comment: Re, "I know it is not possible but ...," There's no point in asking what the laws of physics predict under conditions that are forbidden by the laws of physics.

Comment: Re, "So what's wrong with the thought experiment?" Try thinking about it in terms of limits: How does the signal returning to Earth change as the velocity of the space ship (as seen from Earth) _approaches_ the speed of light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commenters are objecting that a clock cannot travel at the speed of light, so let's modify your thought experiment to preserve its spirit but eliminate that objection:

A beam of light travels from the earth, passing mileposts that are placed every light-second.  Each time it passes a milepost, it triggers a mechanism that sends a message back to earth saying "I've just passed milepost number $N$".

Those signals arrive back on earth at regular intervals.  The  ship passes milepost $30$ at time $30$ (according to the earth-observer) and sends a signal that arrives back on earth at time $60$.  It passes milepost $31$ at time $31$ and sends a signal that arrives back on earth at time $62$.

There's the legitimate version of your thought-experiment.  But notice that in the process of legitimizing it, we removed the paradox.  "Time dilation" is all about comparing the records of two observers.  Here we have one observer---namely you, on earth.  There's nothing to compare and no contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

What you did here was throwing away special relativity and pointing out that the result is in contradiction with special relativity.

As you correctly said, any time interval on the spaceship corresponds to an infinitely long time for a stationary observer, and the signal will never be even sent from that perspective, so the premise of the thought experiment contradicts SR, it's expected that the conclusion contradicts it too.